# How to remove excess arrows using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

A friend and I were messing around with admin accounts and I spawned in too many arrows. We want our world back but don't know how to clear the arrows. We hosted in minehut and have a command window to run commands in. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear: Do you mean the arrows shot from a bow, or arrows dropped on the ground using your drop key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is if you shot the arrows:

```
kill @e[type=arrow]
```

And if you dropped arrow items you can clear all items with:

```
kill @e[type=item]
```

If you don’t know which just run both.

Comment: The question is too unclear to be answered in its current state - we can't tell whether OP is talking about arrow projectile entities or arrow item entities. *Don't make assumptions: ask for clarification instead.*

Comment: I wasn’t really making an assumption as it never came to my head that maybe he was throwing around arrow items. Sorry i didnt realize ill have it include both

Comment: @Penguin Don't apologize. You're doing the right thing by answering the question for the user. However as Expert stated, you COULD ask for clarification OR you COULD provide an answer that hits all the possible scenarios. If we strictly stuck to the code of conduct, no questions would receive answers. I'd recommend adding how to clean up `/give`, `/drop` and others. However, you could also provide the server configuration for "item time to live" which is how long a player has to pick up dropped items. (the de-spawn time, if you will)

Comment: @ColeBusby yes I do understand what you mean, and I have answered to the best of my ability however I can’t add what you have asked for because all i know how to do was kill some entities, I don’t no java commands very well but thought I’d give a simple answer as he seemed like he was just messing around with some commands anyway

Comment: just giving you an idea to protect from the "don't assume" paradigm. :)